# Sqoop export to MySQL, different column order

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to sqoop export from a table on HDFS to MySQL server. The columns are in different order.

My sqoop script is:

```
<workflow-app name="sqoop" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="sqoop"/>
    <action name="sqoop">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
              <arg>export</arg>
              <arg>--connect</arg>
              <arg>jdbc:mysql://10.1.1.1:501/db_name</arg>
              <arg>--username</arg>
              <arg>sqoop</arg>
              <arg>--password-file</arg>
              <arg>/user/sqoop.password</arg>
              <arg>--table</arg>
              <arg>table_name</arg>
              <arg>--export-dir</arg>
              <arg>/user/location</arg>
              <arg>-m</arg>
              <arg>5</arg>
              <arg>--input-fields-terminated-by</arg>
              <arg>\001</arg>
              <arg>--input-null-non-string</arg>
              <arg>\\N</arg>
              <arg>--input-null-string</arg>
              <arg>\\N</arg>
              <arg>--columns</arg>
              <arg>col_1,col_2,col_3</arg>            
            </sqoop>        
            <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

My HDFS table is created as:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table_name`(
  `col_2` bigint, 
  `col_1` bigint, 
  `col_3` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'com.hadoop.mapred.DeprecatedLzoTextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://nameservice1/user/location'
```

and i get the following error:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "AA"
  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

I tried to export to a table with the exact same order and by removing the --columns option from the sqoop script an everything worked fine. Is it just not possible to sqoop to columns with different order?

Comment: Possibly duplicate question. Check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190726/sqoop-export-specific-columns-from-hdfs-to-mysql-is-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, [Sqoop User Guide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_selecting_the_data_to_import)

Answer (score 0):

In the --columns parameter from sqoop export, you must specify the columns in the order they are in Hive:

--columns "col_2,col_1,col_3"