# Sqoop Export specific columns from hdfs to mysql is not working properly

Tags: sqoop

My HDFS file contains 5 columns.

```
emp_no,birth_date,first_name,last_name,hire_date
```

I want to export it with only 3 columns:

```
emp_no,first_name,last_name
```

I am doing it with

```
sqoop export
  --connect jdbc:mysql://mysql.example.com/sqoop
  --username sqoop
  --password sqoop
  --table employees
  --columns "emp_no,first_name,last_name"
  --export-dir /user/dataset/employees
```

But I am getting `emp_no`,`birth_date` and `first_name` in MySQL table.

I am getting 3 columns in my table but one column I want to skip is not happening with `--columns` in `sqoop export`

Comment: It should work,try adding --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --lines-terminated-by '\n'

Comment: Thanks. But I was using those options also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem. Actually I misunderstood option --columns for export.

With --columns option for export, we can select subset of columns or control ordering of the table columns(or destination e.g mysql columns) not the HDFS columns.

This option decides binding of HDFS source columns with columns mentioned in --columns option of the destination table.

e.g. if I mention --columns "col2,col3,col1" in sqoop command
where col1,col2,col3 are mysql table's columns

Then it will bind col2 with first column of the HDFS source and col3 with second column of the HDFS source and so on..

Comment: Did that solve your problem of selectively importing data into MySQL? Could you please provide the query which worked for you?